# What should I do about mold in the corner of a bedroom?

Tags: repair, walls, painting, cleaning

I have what I think is a cold corner in a bedroom. Before we moved in, there was wall paper up for a number of years (as per the house selling photos and when we moved in, house was for sale for 2 years), and when I removed the paper there was no marks or issues with the wall. Now since then there is a very moldy corner next to the ceiling. I have had previous work done to my roof and the water streaming down the walls has since ceased, however there is now no water but just mold. I have washed this continually but can't get rid of it. Do I paper over it? I have found thermal like wall paper that states it is damp and mold proof. Or do I paint with anti mold paint? Or should I pay to have someone out to look at this?

Any help of advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Fix the underlying problem before. There is a reason why you still have mold. I would personally rip that wallpaper and locate the source of humidity/water causing this mold. If the water infiltration was fixed correctly, there shouldn't be any mold unless the affected area wasn't let to dry before sealing the area. In order to properly clean mold, you'll need to properly protect yourself N95 mask and gloves and wash thoroughly the affected area with a solution of water and bleach. 1cup of bleach per gallon of water i'd say. Good Luck